# Making GoTo Sheet Button

Tags: forms, excel, vba

I want to create a "View" Button on top and the list below which contains the sheet names.

e.g

"View"

sheet 1
Sheet 2
Sheet 3
Sheet 4
...   .

If I select Sheet 3 and then click View, it should take me to Sheet 3

I tried macro but it is somehow taking input for a particular sheet only and is taking me to one sheet only even if I select others

Comment: Why note make the cells containing sheet names hyperlinks that go to cell A1 of the sheet name that was clicked on? No VBA required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this routine in a standard code module:

```
Public Sub SelectSheet()
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(Selection(1, 1).Value).Select
End Sub
```

Create a Form Button on the worksheet and give it a caption of `GoTo`.

Assign the macro to the button.

Comment: thanks a lot that works perfectly.